# Wrong arguments passed when invoking custom kernel function with syscall (Linux/Android)

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel

I am trying to add a function to Android kernel. Currently I am able to use `syscall` to invoke that function, but after debugging around with `printk` I find that the syscall number itself is passed to my kernel function as the first argument, making all the other arguments wrong as well... Any ideas on possible reasons for this?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

Adding `asmlinkage` consistently both at definition and declaration (in `syscalls.h`) solves the problem. But still I do not see system functions like `sys_getpid` (defined with `DEFINE_SYSCALL0` macro in `timer.c`) doing this - they only add that macro before their declarations in `syscall.h`. If I follow this the compiling would fail due to inconsistent function signatures at declaration and definition. Explanations...?